# Whatsapp notifications

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, vibration, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I recently updated my samsung note 4 to the latest android version 5.0.1, and since then my whatsapp notification always vibrates even if I turn off the vibrations in the app settings.

If the phone is on mute or ringer then it is fine.

Before the update it was fine even if the phone was on vibrate whatsapp didn't vibrate.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: "I turn off the vibrations it still vibrates" Where did you turn off the vibration setting?

Answer (score -1):

By default the setting is vibrate. If you want to change go to whatsapp setting ---> notification tab. Click notification there you will find vibrate default it has different options like "OFF,DEFAULT,SHORT,LONG" select which is suitable for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's off in the whatsapp settings.

Comment: Mani: The original question clearly states "...even if I turn off the vibrations in the app settings." Please ensure your suggestions are compatible with the specifics of the question asked.